# zooming of pdf file

Tags: iphone, pdf, zooming

Looking at the QuartzDemo sample application, I love the speed of the PDF rending using quartz alone (that is, without using uiwebview). However, when I'm zooming in the PDF it doesn't seem to become more clear like it does in PDF view.

Comment: I had the same problem -- interested to see if someone has a solution. Let us know if you find one yourself.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do achieve this is to implement a CATiledLayer based View and add it as subview of a UIScrollView.

Set the levelsOfDetail to 3 and levelsOfDetailBias to 2 for example (one zoom out level and two zoom in level).

The UIScrollView and CATiledLayer classes will do all the job for you :-)

Answer (score 0):

It's actually just zooming in on a pre-rendered image of the PDF, so it's akin to scaling up a png or similar. To actually zoom the PDF you need to re-render the pdf at a larger scale factor and display only the rect that should be visible.